# Problema na exibição de dados com INNER JOIN

Tags: php, inner-join

bom dia, estou com um probleminha na exibição de dados com Inner Join, a consulta retornou ok, mas na exibição da tabela, ao invés de jogar uma linha apenas, ele está jogando mais de uma, eu gostaria que no campo telefone, ficasse da seguinte maneira: telefone1/telefone2/telefone3 da maneira que tivesse apenas uma linha por usuário e no telefone agrupasse dessa forma, é possível?

```
                         <?
                          $sql_usuarios = 'SELECT * FROM clientes AS tb1 INNER JOIN telefones AS tb2 ON(tb1.id_cliente=tb2.id_cliente_telefone) ORDER BY id_cliente ASC';
                          $executa = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_usuarios);
                          while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($executa)) {
                            $id_cliente = $dados['id_cliente'];
                            $nome_cliente = $dados['nome_cliente'];
                            $melhor_horario = $dados['melhorHorario_cliente'];
                            $telefones = $dados['telefone'];
                            if ($melhor_horario=='m') {
                              $melhor_horario = 'Período da Manhã';
                            }
                            elseif ($melhor_horario=='t') {
                              $melhor_horario = 'Período da Tarde';
                            }
                            else{
                              $melhor_horario = 'Período da Noite';
                            }
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row"><?=$id_cliente;?></th>
                          <td><?=$nome_cliente;?></td>
                          <td><?=$telefones;?></td>
                          <td><?=$melhor_horario;?></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <?}?>
```

Comment: Pesquise pela função GROUP_CONCAT fazendo um GROUP BY por usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua tabela de telefones tiver um campo de "tipo", para registrar se o telefone é comercial, residencial ou celular, e existir apenas um tipo de telefone por cliente, você conseguiria fazer isso usando subselects. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
SELECT id_cliente, nome_cliente, melhorHorario_cliente, 
(select telefone from telefones where id_cliente_telefone = tb1.id_cliente and tipo ='RESIDENCIAL') as telefone1, 
(select telefone from telefones where id_cliente_telefone = tb1.id_cliente and tipo ='COMERCIAL') as telefone2, 
(select telefone from telefones where id_cliente_telefone = tb1.id_cliente and tipo ='CELULAR') as telefone3
FROM clientes AS tb1 ORDER by id_cliente ASC
```

A desvantagem é que se houver muitos dados, pode fazer perda de desempenho.

Se não existe um campo de tipo de telefone,  uma outra maneira de resolver isso seria criar uma coluna única com todos os telefones. Aqui tem um exemplo.

```html
SELECT id_cliente, nome_cliente, melhorHorario_cliente, GROUP_CONCAT(tb2.telefone) as numeros_telefone FROM clientes AS tb1 INNER JOIN telefones AS tb2 ON(tb1.id_cliente=tb2.id_cliente_telefone) order by id_cliente ASC
```

Aqui tem mais informações e exemplos:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/

Comment: Esse ultimo não funcionou, na hora de resgatar ele fala que o index telefone nao existe

Comment: Eu ajustei a segunda query, colocando o alias da tabela.

Comment: continua com erro :( 
Notice: Undefined index: telefone in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\tony-oficial-alterado\exibe-cliente.php on line 155
que no caso é quando tento recuperar o telefone em $telefones = $dados['telefone'];

Comment: resolvido, fiz o seguinte:                   $sql_usuarios = 'SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(tb2.telefone) as numeros_telefone FROM clientes AS tb1 INNER JOIN telefones AS tb2 ON(tb1.id_cliente=tb2.id_cliente_telefone) group by tb1.id_cliente order by id_cliente ASC';